# Oracle 12c database on docker container, status: unhealthy

Tags: database, oracle, macos, docker

I’m trying to install a oracle database on my mac machine, but my container status is unhealthy. after i run this command:
*docker run -d -it --name  store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1*
and check the status by docker ps
it shows that it's unhealthy.
and when i run *docker exec -it  bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"*
I get sqlplus command not found.
this is the logs:

```
Oracle Database 12.2.0.1 Setup
Mon Feb 17 13:46:41 UTC 2020

Check parameters ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/paramChk.log
paramChk.sh is done at 0 sec
untar DB bits ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/untarDB.log
untarDB.sh is done at 38 sec
config DB ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log
mkdir: cannot create directory '/u02/app': No space left on device
mkdir: cannot create directory '/u03/app': No space left on device
mkdir: cannot create directory '/u04/app': No space left on device
mkdir: cannot create directory '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin': No space left on device
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/u02/app/oracle/audit': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/u02/app/oracle/oradata': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/u03/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/u04/app/oracle/redo': No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 137: orapwd: command not found
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 171: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/sqlnet.ora: No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 172: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/sqlnet.ora: No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 173: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/sqlnet.ora: No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 184: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/listener.ora: No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 185: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/listener.ora: No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 186: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/listener.ora: No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 197: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/tnsnames.ora: No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 206: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/tnsnames.ora: No such file or directory
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 209: lsnrctl: command not found
Mon Feb 17 13:47:19 UTC 2020
Start Docker DB configuration
Call configDBora.sh to configure database
Configure DB as oracle user
Setup Database directories ...
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 123: sqlplus: command not found
update password
create pdb : ORCLPDB1
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 141: sqlplus: command not found
Reset Database parameters
/home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh: line 155: sqlplus: command not found
DONE!
Remove password info
Docker DB configuration is complete !
configDB.sh is done at 38 sec
Done ! The database is ready for use .
# ===========================================================================  
# == Add below entries to your tnsnames.ora to access this database server ==  
# ====================== from external host =================================  
ORCLCDB=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<ip-address>)(PORT=<port>))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCLCDB.localdomain)))     
ORCLPDB1=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<ip-address>)(PORT=<port>))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCLPDB1.localdomain)))     
#                                                                              
#ip-address : IP address of the host where the container is running.           
#port       : Host Port that is mapped to the port 1521 of the container.      
# The mapped port can be obtained from running "docker port <container-id>"  
JIT: pid 5408 requesting stop
2017-08-08T17:41:41.417556+00:00
ARCH: Archival disabled due to shutdown: 1090
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled
2017-08-08T17:41:41.436309+00:00
Stopping background process VKTM
2017-08-08T17:41:47.017665+00:00
Instance shutdown complete (OS id: 5408)
Mon Feb 17 14:05:05 UTC 2020
shutdown database
/home/oracle/setup/shutDB.sh: line 53: sqlplus: command not found
stop listener
/home/oracle/setup/shutDB.sh: line 61: lsnrctl: command not found
Start up Oracle Database
Mon Feb 17 14:05:07 UTC 2020
start database
/home/oracle/setup/startupDB.sh: line 53: sqlplus: command not found
start listener
/home/oracle/setup/startupDB.sh: line 61: lsnrctl: command not found
The database is ready for use
```

Comment: The log shows `No space left on device` error. Fix it first.

Comment: can you help us add space to the container?  VM has 12 GB free on its disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prune](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/) your volumes and then make sure your mount volume is under the docker desktop (OSX)> Docker Dashboard> Resources> File sharing

More about [mounting](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance)

Starting an Oracle database server instance: Example

`docker run --name TEST-DB -p 9999:1521 -p 9991:5500 -v /Users/yourusername/data/oracle:/opt/oracle/oradata store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1`

The default user credentials from [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition):
user:sys password:Oradoc_db1.